# probability of exactly two out of three events occuring

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given that we have three disjoint events, a,b,c and their probabilities are given as P(A), P(B), P(A ∪ B) etc, how can we find the probability of only two by three events occurring at one point?

Comment: Why are $A,B,C$ independent?

Comment: What does "etc." mean in this context?  What *exactly* are you told about these probabilities?

Comment: nothing actually, it's just an example of in what terms the answer is supposed to be @lulu

Comment: they're disjoint events @user10354138

Comment: Well, the fact that they are disjoint is a great deal of information.  And, of course, if they are disjoint then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ so you don't need to be given $P(A\cup B)$ separately.

Comment: (A or B or C) and (not A or not B or not C) and (A or B) and (B or C) and (A or C) is another way.

Comment: ok but the qs is about two out of three events occurring - what's your take on my solution? @pkr298

Comment: @Jnl Yes both are correct

Comment: You have already written the answer, haven't you?

Comment: It is correct if the events are independent.

Comment: they're disjoint actually, i updated the qs @user

Comment: @pkr they're disjoint actually, i updated the qs

Comment: I think you should edit your post for clarity.  If the events are disjoint (or, equivalently, mutually exclusive) then, yes...no two of them can occur at the same time.  But of course in this case you don't need to be given things like $P(A\cup B)$.  After all, that is just $P(A)+P(B)$ when $A,B$ are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer has assumed that $A,B$ and $C$ are independent.

A more general formula would be
$$p(A\cap B)+p(B\cap C)+p(C\cap B)-3p(A\cap B\cap C).$$

EXAMPLE

Consider throwing a die. Let $A$ be the event of getting a $6$, $B$ the event of getting a $5$ and $C$ the event of getting at least $5$.

The the probability of precisely two events occurring is $\frac{1}{3}$ whereas your formula gives $\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: what if they're disjoint?

Comment: In the case they are disjoint then every term is zero but the formula is still true.

Comment: It would be 1 if these are the only possibilities and there aren't D,E, etc . Perhaps you should ask another question and  phrase it  precisely with exactly what you are assuming.